# Why do I get a segfault when calling my C++ function with .Call rather than .C?

Tags: c++, r

My end goal is to call some C++ functions from within R, here is a MNWE of where I'm hitting a roadblock. If I'm reading the room correctly, I seem to get a segfault when I call my function with `.Call` but when I call it with `.C` everything works fine.

Here is my short C++ function

```cpp
// test.cpp
#include <iostream>

extern "C" void fnTest() {
  std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}
```

Which I then compiled with

```bash
R CMD SHLIB -o test.so test.cpp
```

Which gave the following output:

```bash
g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -o te
st.so test.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
```

Now within R I did

```r
> dyn.load("test.so")
> .C("fnTest")
Hello
list()
> .Call("fnTest")
Hello

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x30, cause 'memory not mapped'

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection:
```

The documentation that I read for these two functions is [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/CallExternal) and didn't seem to indicate much of a difference in the calling format of the two functions.
I tried several other variations (e.g. I was was able to pass arguments successfully to `.C` but not `.Call`) and didn't have any success.

**What is the proper way to `.Call` a C++ function from within R?**

*Some notes on my eventual use case beyond this minimal example, hopefully this is not an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem):
I have a project with many complicated dependencies which I know how to build with CMake but not directly from g++. I was able to build a shared library from this project that I could then link into an "R compatible" shared library (`R CMD SHLIB -o test.so test.cpp -L/path/to/my/lib/ -l my_lib_name`) which I was able to `dyn.load()` into my R environment. At that point I then ran into the above `.C` vs. `.Call` issue.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading some additional documentation (that I should have found on the first pass), I believe that you cannot `.Call` a function that has a return type of `void`. 
I could not find an explicit mention of this, but no example in the documentation (e.g. [this section](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Handling-R-objects-in-C)) listed a return type other than `SEXP` and at one point the documentation states that:

> All the R objects you will deal with will be handled with the type SEXP

On the other hand, as documented in the [Interface functions .C and .Fortran section](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Interface-functions-_002eC-and-_002eFortran), any function that you `.C` *must* have a return type of void:

> Note that the compiled code should not return anything except through its arguments: C functions should be of type void and Fortran subprograms should be subroutines.

Here are some examples that can be compiled as in the OP. It didn't seem like there was a default "null" return type for `.Call`'ed functions, but <s>`allocVector(REALSXP, 0)`</s> `R_NilValue` seemed to work well.

```cpp
// test.cpp

#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>

extern "C" void fnPrintC() {
  Rprintf("Hello world!\n");
}

extern "C" SEXP fnPrintCall() {
  Rprintf("Hello world!\n");

  // return allocVector(REALSXP, 0);
  return R_NilValue;
}

extern "C" SEXP fnAddCall(SEXP a, SEXP b) {
  double* xa = REAL(a);
  double* xb = REAL(b);

  SEXP ans = allocVector(REALSXP, 2);
  REAL(ans)[0] = *xa + *xb;
  REAL(ans)[1] = *xa - *xb;

  return ans;
}
```

Here they are called from R. Note we can send the (`void`) output to the dummy variable `x` if we don't want to see it.

```R
> dyn.load("test.so")

> x <- .C("fnPrintC")
> Hello world!

> x <- .Call("fnPrintCall")
> Hello world!

> .Call("fnAddCall", 4, 3)
> [1] 7 1
```

In general, the documentation linked above was pretty helpful, I recommend starting there for anyone with a similar question, I certainly wish I'd read it more thoroughly earlier on.

Comment: I'm following this question because I am new to C and C++ and want to learn stuff. Did you also try for example
return R_NilValue

Comment: You are welcome! Does it print out "NULL" to the console or is that suppressed, such that only "Hello World" is printed?

Comment: In my sample code it prints nothing since NULL is sent to the x variable, but yes, if you don't send it to a variable it will print NULL